# active_for_authentication? not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using active_for_authentication? to allow only active users to login through devise.
But it's not working.

My controller:

```
class DashboardUsersController < ApplicationController
def active_for_authentication?
  super && self.deactivated_ind
end

def inactive_message
  "Sorry, this account has been deactivated."
end
```

My model:

```
class DashboardUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable,:rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable

  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["username = :value OR lower(email) = lower(:value)", { :value => login }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
end
```

My user table:

```
t.string   "deactivated_ind",      limit: 1
t.date     "deactivated_date"
```

By using deactivated_ind Y / N i check user is active / inactive.
Now i want allow devise to log in only those user have N in deactivated_ind colomn

Answer (score 4):

1. `active_for_authentication?` needs to be a method on a **model**, not on a controller
2. (not a problem in your case, but was mine) `active_for_authentication?` must be a **public** method on a model

Comment: I got tripped up since I usually make all Devise callback method overrides I write `private`, but `active_for_authentication` (and it's companion `inactive_message` method), would seem to _need_ to be `public`.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem, I'm guessing is that you're using a string for "deactivated_ind" instead of a boolean.  A string of "N" and a string of "Y" will both be true when you try to use them as boolean values, since neither is nil.